# SyntaxError: Unexpected token M in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json

A simplified version of my JSON object is the following one:

```
{"Results":[{"Value": "00145"}, {"Value": "MOODY'S NUMBER"}]}
```

I am using `JSON.parse()` on each of the string values of the `Value` property.
So `JSON.parse` for the first one returns me `"00145"`, but for the second one it throws me the following exception:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token M in JSON at position 0`

I am not sure what might've caused this.

Comment: `00145` is valid JSON, quite useless but valid. `MOODY'S NUMBER` is invalid. Why do you `JSON.parse(...)` on those strings?

Comment: How are you accessing the first one - can you add that here  which returns `00145` ?

Comment: I've got a schema and I'm mapping all the properties into that schema, and afterwards I can easily access each property. So I'm passing the raw value of the string straight into the JSON.parse()

Comment: You have to escape restricted characters in string before parsing, use something like here https://gist.github.com/matthewmueller/3459332

Comment: So did you pass for example, `JSON.parse ("00145")` ?

Comment: You don't use JSON.parse on individual properties. You use it on the entire schema/object/data structure

Comment: @AksJacoves yes

Comment: This is not possible, it will generate an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1`

Comment: You use `JSON.parse` to convert a json string to a json object

Comment: I think, you want to put double quotes here; see my answer for details

Comment: Ah okay, thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MOODY'S NUMBER` is not a valid JSON, that's why you observe this error.

While the whole provided string can be parsed to JSON (as it is syntactically valid):

```json
{"Results":[{"Value": "00145"}, {"Value": "MOODY'S NUMBER"}]}
```

… it doesn't mean that each subset of the string is also syntactically valid as well:

```js
JSON.parse("00145");
// 00145

JSON.parse("MOODY'S NUMBER");
// SyntaxError!
```

Perhaps, you want to construct the string `"MOODY'S NUMBER"`? Then try these options:

```js
const input = '{"Results":[{"Value": "00145"}, {"Value": "MOODY\'S NUMBER"}]}';

const result = JSON.parse(input).Results[2].Value;
// "MOODY'S NUMBER"
```

… or (notice double quotes):

```js
JSON.parse('"MOODY\'S NUMBER"');
// "MOODY'S NUMBER"
```